# WPF coerced DependencyProperty value change does not update that property's binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, .net-4.8

I am using a custom control in my WPF application, which is a subclass of the standard TextBox, meant for holding a number within a certain allowed range. This control has three dependency properties - the number itself, a minimum and a maximum:

```
public class NumberTextBox : TextBox
{
    public double Number
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(NumberProperty);
        set => SetValue(NumberProperty, value);
    }

    public double Minimum
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty);
        set => SetValue(MinimumProperty, value);
    }

    public double Maximum
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty);
        set => SetValue(MaximumProperty, value);
    }

    public static DependencyProperty NumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Number), typeof(double), typeof(NumberTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        {
            DefaultValue = 0.0,
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            CoerceValueCallback = new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceNumber),
            PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(NumberChanged)
        });

    public static DependencyProperty MinimumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Minimum), typeof(double), typeof(NumberTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        {
            DefaultValue = double.MinValue,
            PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(LimitsChanged)
        });

    public static DependencyProperty MaximumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Maximum), typeof(double), typeof(NumberTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        {
            DefaultValue = double.MaxValue,
            PropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(LimitsChanged)
        });

    private static void NumberChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        NumberTextBox sender = (NumberTextBox)dependencyObject;
        sender.Text = eventArgs.NewValue.ToString();
    }

    private static object CoerceNumber(DependencyObject dependencyObject, object baseValue)
    {
        NumberTextBox sender = (NumberTextBox)dependencyObject;
        double value = (double)baseValue;
        if (value < sender.Minimum)
            return sender.Minimum;
        else if (value > sender.Maximum)
            return sender.Maximum;
        else
            return baseValue;
    }

    private static void LimitsChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        dependencyObject.CoerceValue(NumberProperty);
    }
}
```

If this control does not seem to be particularly useful, it is because this is a simplified version of my actual control for the sake of readability, the problem in question is replicated by this code.

I particularly want the minimum / maximum limits to be enforced on the held number when they change, for example if Number and Maximum are both at 100 and then Maximum reduces to 99, I want Number to be changed to 99 as well to comply with the maximum value. That's why I call CoerceValue(NumberProperty) in the min / max PropertyChanged handler.

Additionally, I have the Number dependency property bound to a property on a class in the control's data context. Any change of Number I want to be passed to that property as well.

Unfortunately, that last part does not work. The code above will (seemingly) correctly execute the LimitsChanged, CoerceNumber and NumberChanged handlers and the Number property on the control itself will then hold the expected value - but that value change is not passed on the bound property in the data context. So, sticking to the above example, the property in the data context will still hold the value 100 after Maximum and Number on the control have been reduced to 99.

I do not understand why, as Number has changed and the dependency property is defined to use TwoWay binding by default (explicitly setting Mode=TwoWay in the XAML binding does not work either). I cannot set Number to an explicit value in the control's code, as that would break any bindings on that property from that point onwards.

Any help with making the Number property coercion be passed on to the bound property would be greatly appreciated.